Published PowerApp changes not showing
I have a Sharepoint form which I am customizing using PowerApps. I have made the changes I want and have saved and published the app. However, when I go back to the Sharepoint List and enter a new item via the form, the form still appears to be the default form and does not show the changes I made.
Any idea on how to show those changes?
Thank you!

Hi,You can see these changes in PowerApp yes? Just making sure you save.

We ususally put a version number on the form and show the version to the user on the landing page, Then we instruct the user to open the form and refresh until the versions match. Looks like it's being cached on microsoft servers for users, not even in their browsers. And changes are not made instant anyway. Best you can see it in the Power Apps not attached to SP lists. Once you update it and go to the Modern Page with web part that displays the app, it informs you that the new version is available (some time after the update) and whether you want to use the updated version.
